# Delphi FireMonkey TListBox AddObject exception on Android

Tags: android, delphi, listbox, firemonkey, tobject

I'm having a problem adding a `TObject` value to a FireMonkey `TListBox` in Delphi 10.0 Seattle.

An exeception is raised when casting an `Integer` variable to a `TObject` pointer.

I tried the cast to `TFmxObject` with no success.  On Windows, the cast works like a charm, but on Android it raises the exception.

Here is my code:

```
var
  jValue:TJSONValue;
  i,total,id: integer;
  date: string;
begin
  while (i < total) do
  begin
    date := converteDate(jValue.GetValue('date' + IntToStr(i), ''));
    id := StrToInt(jValue.GetValue('id' + IntToStr(i), ''));
    ListBox1.Items.AddObject(date, TObject(id));
    i := i + 1;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that on iOS and Android (and soon Linux), `TObject` uses [Automatic Reference Counting](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers) for lifetime management, and as such you cannot type-cast integer values as `TObject` pointers, like you can on Windows and OSX, which do not use ARC. On ARC systems, `TObject` pointers **must** point to real objects, as the compiler is going to perform reference-counting semantics on them.  That is why you are getting an exception.

To do what you are attempting, you will have to wrap the integer value inside of a real object on ARC systems, eg:

```
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
type
  TIntegerWrapper = class
  public
    Value: Integer;
    constructor Create(AValue: Integer);
  end;

constructor TIntegerWrapper.Create(AValue: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Value := AValue;
end;
{$ENDIF}

...

ListBox1.Items.AddObject(date, {$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}TIntegerWrapper.Create(id){$ELSE}TObject(id){$ENDIF});

...

{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
id := TIntegerWrapper(ListBox1.Items.Objects[index]).Value;
{$ELSE}
id := Integer(ListBox1.Items.Objects[index]);
{$ENDIF}
```

Otherwise, store your integers in a separate list and then use the indexes of the `TListBox` items as indexes into that list when needed, eg:

```
uses
  .., System.Generics.Collections;

private
  IDs: TList<Integer>;

...

var
  ...
  Index: Integer;
begin    
  ...
  Index := IDs.Add(id);
  try
    ListBox1.Items.Add(date);
  except
    IDs.Delete(Index);
    raise;
  end;
  ...
end;

...

Index := ListBox1.Items.IndexOf('some string');
id := IDs[Index];
```

This is portable to all platforms without having to use `IFDEF`s or worrying about ARC.

Comment: Can you help me, I have similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927994/tlistbox-items-addobject-firemonkey-10-2  where put {$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}

Comment: @Pointer how is that question any different than this one? I'm inclined to close that question as a duplicate