# TListBox Items AddObject Firemonkey 10.2

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm try on formShow add

```
ListBox1.Items.AddObject('TEST 1', TObject(1)) ;
ListBox1.Items.AddObject('TEST 2', TObject(2)) ;
```

but app automatically close (crash).

This example work fine

```
ListBox1.Items.Add('TEST 1');
ListBox1.Items.Add('TEST 2');
```

Any solution how use Items.AddObject?

Comment: If you are on mobile then you cannot use this trick to typecast a constant as an object pointer.

Comment: @Hans I need Text and Value on VCL ListBox1.Items.AddObject('TEST 1', TObject(1)) ;   work fine.

Comment: @Pointer, in mobile, objects are managed with the ARC memory model. Since 1 is not an object, it will fail.

Comment: Use a class with a single integer field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `FMX TListBox` I suggest you use the `Tag` property instead.

```
aItem: TListBoxItem;
begin
   aItem := TListBoxItem.Create(Self);
   aItem.Text := 'TEST 1';
   aItem.Tag := 1;
   aItem.Parent := ListBox1;

   aItem := TListBoxItem.Create(Self);
   aItem.Text := 'TEST 2';
   aItem.Tag := 2;
   aItem.Parent := ListBox1;
end
```

This is just a pseudo-code, but you get the idea. It also gives you the ability to derive a class from `TListBoxItem` and make it do something that normal `TListBoxItem` will not do or have different class for different items.